# add function for an address book

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
var bob = {
firstName: "Bob",
lastName: "Jones",
phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
firstName: "Mary",
lastName: "Johnson",
phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}
function add(firstName,lastName,email,phoneNumber)
{
}
```

I don't know how and what to write within the add function that will help me to add more contacts. please help me! thanks

Comment: `contacts.push({firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName, email:email, phoneNumber: phoneNumber});`

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(firstName,lastName,email,phoneNumber) { 
        var test_user=
        {
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName":lastName,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
        "email": email
      };

        contacts.push(test_user);

        }
```